# Unexpectedly found nil for optional value - but optional value is not nil

Tags: swift, option-type, audiokit

I'm using [AudioKit](http://audiokit.io/) to set up a sounds player. My sounds engine is set up in a singleton with these functions:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureAudioPlayer()
}

func configureAudioPlayer() {
    leftPanner = AKPanner(leftOscillator)
    rightPanner = AKPanner(rightOscillator)

    //Set up rain and rainPlayer
    do {
        rain = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "rain.wav")
        rainPlayer = try AKAudioPlayer(file: rain, looping: true, deferBuffering: false, completionHandler: nil)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    mixer = AKMixer(leftPanner, rightPanner, rainPlayer)
    envelope = AKAmplitudeEnvelope(mixer)

    AudioKit.output = envelope
    AudioKit.start()
}

func startPlaying() {
    leftOscillator.start()
    rightOscillator.start()
    rainPlayer.start() //CRASHES HERE AND SAYS NIL OPTIONAL VALUE
    envelope.start()

    soundIsPlaying = true
}
```

In a separate view controller I have a play button that calls the following function when pressed:

```
let player = AudioPlayer.sharedPlayer

@IBAction func playSound(_ sender: Any) {
    player.leftOscillator.frequency = 220
    player.rightOscillator.frequency = 230

    if player.soundIsPlaying == false {
        player.startPlaying()
    } else {
        player.stopPlaying()
    }
}
```

When I press this button the app crashes and says that the rainPlayer is nil. Did I set something up wrong? Why would the rainPlayer be nil when I configured it in the configureAudioPlayer() function?

UPDATE:
Moving the singleton into its own class that inherits from NSObject and calling configureAudioPlayer() in its init() function solves my problem. configureAudioPlayer() in the viewDidLoad() method was never being called.

Comment: Where/when is `configureAudioPlayer()` called?

Comment: It's called in the viewDidLoad() of the same singleton class.

Comment: Do you ever see an error printed to the console at runtime?

Comment: Usually a singleton class is not a subclass of a view controller, therefore it has no `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: The only error I get is the "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Is it bad if my singleton is a subclass of a view controller? I am using my "audio controls" view controller which has the pause/play button etc as my singleton.

Comment: I guess it is bad because most likely `viewDidLoad` is not called at all and this caused the error.

Comment: I put "print("test")" in the viewDidLoad of the singleton and it shows up in the console so it looks like it is being called. Could there be another thing I am doing wrong?

Comment: The *shared* instance is possibly not the same instance as the view controller in the view hierarchy. In this instance `viewDidLoad` is not called. Reconsider your design.

Comment: I will put my shared instance in a separate class from my audio controls and update this question with my results.